# Showing that a series in $l_{\infty}$ converges weakly, given a boundedness condition.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand the following:

> Let $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of elements in $l_{\infty}$ such that for some constant $K$, $$\|\sum_{1}^n \lambda_k x_k \|\leq K\sup_k |\lambda_k| \quad \textrm{for all} \ \{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^n\subset \mathbb{R}, \quad n=1,2,\dots$$ Then for every bounded sequence $\{\lambda\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{R}$ the series $\sum_1^{\infty} \lambda_k x_k$ converges weakly to an element of norm $\leq K \sup_k |\lambda_k |$ in $l_{\infty}$.

From the stated condition we can say that the $\sup$ of the inequality's LHS is finite. Does that imply the convergence of the series? (Which would mean strong convergence, implying weak convergence) If not, how can I convince myself of the weak convergence?

Comment: I don't expect strong convergence here; don't try to prove it. Also, I'm not sure about the intended meaning of "weak convergence" here. Read literally, it means for every $f\in \ell_\infty^*$ the series $\sum \lambda_k f(x_k)$ converges. I don't see how to prove this. But people rarely consider the weak topology on $\ell_\infty$; usually they work with the weak* topology inherited from $\ell_1^* = \ell_\infty$. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: Hi there, thanks. Yeah, the original text refers to "the $w^* $ topology induced by the elements of $l_1$", so I assumed they meant the weak topology since $l_1$ is isomorphic to the dual of $l_{\infty}$. It's Lemma 3 in Joram Lindenstrauss' paper "On complemented subspaces of $m$". Could you tell me what they mean by that?

Comment: $l_1$ is not isomorphic to the dual of $l_\infty$. They mean [weak-* topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak-.2A_topology)

Comment: Right, it's the other way around. Thank you for the clarifications and the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\sup_{k\ge 1} |\lambda_k|$. By assumption, the partial sums $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k x_k$ satisfy  $\|s_n\|_\infty\le MK$ for all $n$. For bounded sequences, weak* convergence in $\ell_\infty$  is precisely the coordinate-wise convergence. Thus, we only need to check that for each fixed index $j$ the numeric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k x_k(j)$ converges.

Fix $j$. For each $k$, choose $\mu_k \in\{1,-1\} $ so that  $\mu_k x_k(j) =  |x_k(j)|$.
By assumption, the partial sums of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_k x_k(j) $ are bounded by $K$, which implies 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k(j)|$ converges to a number at most $K$. Thus, 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k x_k(j)$ converges and
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k x_k(j )\right| \le M\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k(j)| \le MK$$